# column wise dictionary creation using python

Tags: python, csv

How to make a columnwise dictionary from csv using python?

```
name, lastname, hobby
jhon, g, fishing
mike, a, boxing
tom, v, sking
```

output should be :

```
name = {1 : 'jhon', 2:'mike', 3:'tom'}
lastname = {1 : 'g', 2:'a', 3:'v'}
hobby = {1 : 'fishing', 2:'boxing', 3:'sking'}
```

Comment: Why use a dictionary at all? A list would be more efficient; `name = ['jhon', 'mike', 'tom']` and use normal indexing.

Comment: @sam Agree with Martijn Pieters - position of a record in list is denoting index in data.

Comment: And why not creating a class `Person` containing all the informations and then just create one list to stock all the results instead of 3 list/dico

Comment: I want dict because I wanted to compare the dicts afterwords.

Comment: You can compare the *lists* afterwards too.

Comment: We shall respect right of OP to ask what he thinks is needed.

Comment: can I get common and difference between lists like sets in dictionary?

Comment: @sam: then use *sets*. Your dictionary won't give you what is common or different either, you can only do that with the *keys*, which are just sequential numbers, and won't have any differences (they will all 3 give you the numbers 1 through to N, where N is the number of rows).

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: Not if there is a better way to solve the *problem*. Looks like there is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: to be in simpler words, I need to find and print common and difference of 2 columns values. This is the reason I wanted to create dict and then use sets. If there is any good method available, I will learn that too.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can get both list or dictionary very easily:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> csvfile = StringIO('''name, lastname, hobby
... jhon, g, fishing
... mike, a, boxing
... tom, v, sking''')
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
>>> dict(df['name'])
{0: 'jhon', 1: 'mike', 2: 'tom'}
>>> list(df['name'])
['jhon', 'mike', 'tom']
```

Comment: Just put filename to `read_csv` method: `df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea based on matrix transpose.

You get tuples but of course you can cast to lists, sets, dicts or whatever afterwards.

```
_ = raw_input()

m = []

for _ in range(3):
    m.append(raw_input().split(', '))
name, lastname, hobby = zip(*m)

print name
print lastname
print hobby
```

Comment: how csv file can be used in this?

Comment: The data are read in the standard input, for instance on a unix-like OS, I use the script like this.

`python script.py < data.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
# read the csv table
data = [x.strip().split(', ') for x in open('csv').readlines()] 

# transpose the table
data_transposed = map(list, zip(*data))
```

Now go over the data_transposed rows and create the desired dicts:

```
for row in data_transposed:
    # the dictionary name is the first element
    name = row[0]
    # the remaining elements are enumerated and put in a dict
    d = dict(enumerate(row[1:]))
    print name, "=", d
```